# Rebuild CMake target when dependency changes

Tags: c++, cmake

There are countless similar questions on here but I can't find one that addresses exactly this issue:

I'm using to CMake to build shared libraries `a` and `b` and executable `prog`. `prog` should be linked against `a` but not against `b`. However, at the same time I want `prog` to be rebuilt whenever `b` is outdated. In practical terms, `b` is a compiler plugin used while building `prog`.

I have tried:

```
add_library(a a.cc)
add_library(b b.cc)
add_dependencies(a b)

add_executable(prog prog.cc)
target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE a)
```

But this does not work, when `b` needs to be rebuilt this does not result in `prog` being rebuilt as well.

I have also tried:

```
add_library(a a.cc)
add_library(b b.cc)
target_link_libraries(a INTERFACE b)

add_executable(prog prog.cc)
target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE a)
```

But this causes `prog` to be linked against `b`. Is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: `I want prog to be rebuilt whenever b is outdated` what for? They are unrelated. `b is a compiler plugin used while building prog` "How" exactly is it "used"? When building `prog.cc` to the object file or when linking `prog` together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that generator expression do not work in `OBJECT_DEPENDS` context. Touché. Anyway, just do a small proxy:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
add_library(a a.cpp)
add_library(b b.cpp)
add_executable(prog prog.cpp)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b_is_build
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b_is_build
  DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:b>
)
set_source_files_properties(prog.cpp PROPERTIES
  OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b_is_build
)
```

Then touching `b.cpp` rebuilds prog:

```
+ touch b.cpp
+ cmake --build _build --verbose
[1/5] /usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o -c /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/b.cpp
[2/5] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libb.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libb.a  CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libb.a && :
[3/5] cd /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build && /usr/bin/cmake -E touch /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/b_is_build
[4/5] /usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/prog.dir/prog.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/prog.dir/prog.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/prog.dir/prog.cpp.o -c /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/prog.cpp
[5/5] : && /usr/bin/c++   CMakeFiles/prog.dir/prog.cpp.o -o prog  liba.a && :
```

---

> b is a compiler plugin used while building prog

Ideally would be to  tell CMake that *object files* depend on that plugin *file*, however `$<TARGET_FILE` does not work here.

```
set_source_file_properties(prog.cc PROPERTIES
     OBJECT_DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:b>
)
```

Or tell CMake that that linking the resulting program depends on on the plugin, depending where exactly that plugin is used.

```
set_target_properties(prog PROPERTIES
     LINK_DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:b>
)
```

Dependencies are modeled on *files* - for example executable file `prog` depends on file `b`. `add_dependencies` only does ordering (one is build before the other).

---

Comment: The first option sounds like what I want. Unfortunately it does not seem to work after a quick test, object files are not rebuilt when b changes.

Comment: Actually CMake even refuses to expand the generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE:b>` at all which seems like a bug because it works in other places just not inside `set_source_files_properties`.

Comment: Och, then first get the target property and use the file path from property. So it will not work with multi-generators, odd. Anyway, to summarize, the plugin is used to when creating object files, right?

Comment: @Peter Edited the answer! ;)

Comment: This seems to only work when `add_source_files_properties` is called in the same file in which the custom target is defined. So technically it answers the question but is very limited. Is there no way around that?

Comment: No - source file properties are limited to directory scope.

Comment: That in itself is fine, I mean that it's not possible to depend on `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b_is_build` from another directory. I'll accept for now anyways.

Comment: Hm.... indeed seems so. You still can do `add_custom_command(DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:b>` from anywhere, so just do it from the same dir as source is added.

Comment: That's what I did now and it works, thanks a lot!